# Make phone wake up using the volume keys?

Tags: nexus-one

Is it possible to make the phone (N1) wake up some other way than using the power button without rooting the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not believe this is possible. No app can interact with the phone once the phone has been locked / put into standby mode... therefore without installing a custom ROM (which has modified the code allowing other buttons to unlock / wake up the phone) this is not possible.

Comment: I have bought a Nexus 4 and now use KitKat OS. Is this possible on it?